# Docker failed to start

Tags: linux, docker, systemd, ulimit

Today I have an issue with docker, It stopped and I cannot start it

```
 systemctl status docker

● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-01-28 09:59:03 +0330; 1min 51s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 2327 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=205/LIMITS)
 Main PID: 2327 (code=exited, status=205/LIMITS)

Jan 28 09:59:03 example.com systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Jan 28 09:59:03 example.com systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=205/LIMITS
Jan 28 09:59:03 example.com systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Jan 28 09:59:03 example.com systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Jan 28 09:59:03 example.com systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

I see that I have `status=205/LIMITS` I remember that 3 day ago I changed `ulimit` configs

```
# /etc/security/limits.d/custom.conf

root soft nofile 1000000
root hard nofile 1000000
* soft nofile 1000000
* hard nofile 1000000
```

```
# /etc/sysctl.conf

fs.file-max = 1000000
fs.nr_open = 1000000
```

I increased fd to 1 million , after undo changes docker started successfully

What is problem here exactly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`status=205/LIMITS` mean one of these limit hits `LimitCPU=, LimitFSIZE=, LimitDATA=, LimitSTACK=, LimitCORE=, LimitRSS=, LimitNOFILE=, LimitAS=, LimitNPROC=, LimitMEMLOCK=, LimitLOCKS=, LimitSIGPENDING=, LimitMSGQUEUE=, LimitNICE=, LimitRTPRIO=, LimitRTTIME=`

I am not sure about your OS version but giving one example for Ubuntu 16 create this file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/customexec.conf` if doesn't exists  with below content.

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=1000000
```

Do reload `systemctl daemon-reload`

The docker package set a limit higher than our new limit, so the process was failing to start. So you can try below if above option doesn't work for you.

`sysctl -w fs.nr_open=1048576`

Comment: I am using centos 7.7 , before posing in serverfault I edited ` /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service` and set `LimitNOFILE=1000000` and then run `systemctl daemon-reload`, Also tries `LimitNOFILE=ulimit` , it doesn't works
**My question is : I increased `ulimit -n` fron default(1024) to 1000000 , Why docker works with 1024 but not 1000000**

Comment: can you add what you tried to your questions? also share journalctl logs for docker service when it was giving this exception.